# How to execute jar file with options using java program?

Tags: java, command-line, processbuilder, openapi-generator-cli

I am executing following command using java program but not getting result and getting exitCode is 1 with mentioned output.

**Command**

```
java -jar openapi-generator-cli.jar generate -g spring -i petstore.yml --skip-validate-spec -o output/
```

**Java Program**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    
    String filePath = "C:\\swagger-to-code-poc\\swagger-to-code\\src\\main\\resources\\";
    String jarFileName = "openapi-generator-cli.jar";
    Process process = exec(filePath, jarFileName);
    System.out.println(process.info());
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    //BufferedInputStream errorBufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(process.getErrorStream());
    synchronized (process) {
        process.waitFor(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    String line;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    int exitCode = process.waitFor();
    System.out.println("ExitCode : "+exitCode);

    reader.close();
}

public static Process exec(String path, String filename) throws IOException {
    String javaHome = System.getProperty("java.home");
    String javaBin = javaHome +
            File.separator + "bin" +
            File.separator + "java";

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(javaBin, "-jar", path+filename, "generate",
            "-i C:\\swagger-to-code-poc\\swagger-to-code\\src\\main\\resources\\petstore.yml", "-g spring",
            "-o C:\\swagger-to-code-poc\\swagger-to-code\\src\\main\\resources\\output\\");

    System.out.println("Command : "+pb.command());
    return pb.start();
}
```

petstore.yml and openapi-generator-cli.jar exists in `/src/main/resources/` folder

**Console Output**

```
Command : [C:\Eclipse_2020-06\jdk-11.0.7+10\bin\java, -jar, C:\swagger-to-code-poc\swagger-to-code\src\main\resources\openapi-generator-cli.jar, generate, -i C:\swagger-to-code-poc\swagger-to-code\src\main\resources\petstore.yml, -g spring, -o C:\swagger-to-code-poc\run-using-cli\output\]
[cmd: C:\Eclipse_2020-06\jdk-11.0.7+10\bin\java.exe, startTime: Optional[2023-06-25T18:19:21.457Z], totalTime: Optional[PT0.015625S]]
ExitCode : 1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Use `return pb.redirectErrorStream(true).start()` and ditch the `process.waitFor(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`, then you should see any error messages.

Comment: I also suspect parameters like `"-g spring"`  - I would use `"-g", "spring"`, but I do not know what parameters the JAR is expecting... || maybe adding `pb.inheritIO()` helps seeing any error message or other output

Comment: Thanks, Error gone, but process taking too much time and not displaying command output.